# Phoenix: render JSON from a template

Tags: json, templates, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to create a very simple case: a controller action which renders a static JSON, from a template.

controller:

```
defmodule MyApp.TestController do
  use Phoenix.Controller

  def show(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "show.json")
  end
end
```

view:

```
defmodule MyApp.TestView do
  use MyApp.Web, :view
end
```

`show.json.eex`:

```
{
  "message": "Hello, world!"
}
```

The problem is, I get the proper JSON response, but JSON-encoded:

```
"{\n  \"message\": \"Hello, world!\"\n}"
```

Any idea why, and how to solve it?

/Edit:

I found out that I can work around the problem by renaming the template to something other than `json` (plus explicitly setting response type, of course), so obviously JSON templates are additionally encoded. But why, who would want such a thing?

Answer (score 7):

After further investigation and talking with people on Phoenix Slack channel, I have a clearer picture about what's going on:

Phoenix is agnostic when it comes to deciding whether the content comes from a template or from a data structure in the view. `render/2` from the controller happily takes anything and converts it to JSON.

I wrote up a [more detailed blog post](http://stari-blog.radioni.ca/2016/10/02/phoenix-and-json-templates.html) about this issue, along with several approaches in addressing it, and in my opinion every is a workaround for the inherent problem in Phoenix (which, admittedly, is far from critical).

Essentially, one should avoid executing `Poison.encode` function, which gets called from `render_to_iostream` function. You can do that either by not using `.json` as the template extension, by directly calling `Phoenix.View.render` from the controller, or by creating custom encoder and template engine to pass some metadata along with the data to be output.

Comment: but how to get the json values from postgresql??